# Autolayout : Update constraints on UICollectionViewCell doesn't work

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, uicollectionviewcell

I have a problem while trying to update my UILabel constraints on my collectionViewCell.
My prototype cell look like :

[image: Cell Prototype]

My goal is : I need to edit the constant of the red label top constraints, depending if I hide or not the green label.

### How did I proceed?

- I added an IBoutlet for the constraint on the red label (the one with the red arrow):

  `@IBOutlet weak var descriptionTopToPrice: NSLayoutConstraint!`
- Then :

  `descriptionTopToPrice.constant = 2`

  `self.contentView.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()`

But it doesn't work, and the constraints doesn't update.

Did I miss something?

Comment: Have you tried layoutIfNeeded()? I normally use that and have never had a problem.

Comment: How are you hiding/unhiding the green label? When you do that hide/unhide what happens when you attempt a reload of the cell? Either by calling reloadData on your UICollectionView or targeting the specific cell with reloadItemsAtIndexPaths.

Comment: Thank you, it wasn't layoutIfNeeded(), I forgot to ad a width/height constraint..! i didn't need to reload cell

Answer (score 0):

In your approach you must hardcode the value of the constraint in your code. For similar goal I usually made 2 constraints, one for the default layout and one for the change. You can set the priority of the second one to be lower than the first one. This way the you can later just remove the first constraint in your code and call the layout method. Thus, the second constraint with the lower priority will take its place.